# AttributeError: 'ExampleView' object has no attribute 'data' django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have to write a custom function inside class based view which is like below.

```
class ExampleView(ListCreateAPIView,
                  DestroyAPIView,
                 RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'PUT' and kwargs.get('slug'):
            return self.custom_function(request,*args,**kwargs)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)    

    
    def custom_function(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        print(instance)
        slug = kwargs.get("slug")
        print(slug)
        print(request.data)
```

Here I can see that from dispatch, the custom function is called and I can see the print of instance and slug but when I print(request.data) it says the error below:

**AttributeError: 'ExampleView' object has no attribute 'data'**

I need request.data to perform some logic in the data.

Comment: That error would suggest you are calling `self.data` rather than on a request object. Have you defined an urpattern for `ExampleView.as_view()` or are you calling it with  `ExampleView.as_view()(request)`?

Comment: I am calling as request.data . Isnt this the way of getting data?? Also my url is `path("example/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/",admin.ExampleView.as_view()),`

Comment: It's not obvious from what you posted. This would usually be caused by forgetting to define `self` as the the first argument of the method, but I can see that you have done that in this example